# How to copy value from one wpdb->insert query into another wpdb->insert query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am successfully inserting data into two tables but I can't add `$wpdb->insert_id` into the third table. I have 3 queries. In the first query, I have not specified the id because it should be automated. So it's from the first query that the second query picks the `$wpdb->insert_id`. I assume this should be similar to the third table because the second query inserts the id. I am supplying the same $wpdb->insert_id into the 3rd query. I'm not sure what's missing. I was wondering whether there is a way we can somehow get the id from the second query into the 3rd query if the `$wpdb->insert_id` won't work.

```
global $wpdb;
$msg = '';
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? trim($_GET['action']) : "";
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : "";

$row_details = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT * from wp_appointments WHERE id = %d", $id
        ), ARRAY_A
);

if (isset($_POST['save-multiple-data'])) {
if (empty($action)) {
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? trim($_GET['action']) : "";
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : "";

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["location"]); $i++) {
  $wpdb->insert("wp_appointments", array(
      "location_id" => $_POST["location"][$i],
      "service_id" => $_POST["service"][$i],
  ));

  $wpdb->insert("wp_appointment_customers", array(
      "appointment_id" => $wpdb->insert_id,
      "customer_id" => '1',
      "status" => 'pending',
  ));

$wpdb->insert("wp_appointment_custom_data", array(
      "appointment_id" => $wpdb->insert_id,
      "customer_id" => '1',
      "form_input_id" => '9',
      "input_value" => '46',
  ));
  
}

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you are trying to get the value of the insert_id of the first insert into the 3rd insert, it won't work as the value of the insert_id will change after the second insert. You should save the value of the first `$wpdb->insert_id` in a separate variable right after the first insert and then use that variable to store the id into the other two tables.

Comment: @shivaramanaiyer I tried ```$insertId = $wpdb->insert_id;
$wpdb->insert("wp_bkntc_appointment_custom_data", array(
      "appointment_id" => $insertId,));```  but it still didn't work. How do you redefine?

Comment: What value is being stored in the DB?

Comment: For the 3rd query it's ```"customer_id" => '1',
      "form_input_id" => '9',
      "input_value" => '46',```

Comment: Okay  but the second query is storing correctly?